# Clunking sound?

Tags: chevrolet, steering, noise, malibu

I just purchased a previously owned `2008 Chevrolet Malibu` with `100,000 K` on it.
Whenever I make a sharp left or right turn (making a 90 degree turn rather than a shallow turn), the front end makes a *clunk* sound after I pull out of the turn while centering the steering wheel. It also does this *clunking* when I accelerate hard or brake hard (this doesn't happen as frequently as turning). 
The previous owner claims to have had the CV joints, brake pads and rotors changed before he decided to sell the car.
What could be the issue? How do I go about diagnosing it?
I'd appreciate any insight on this

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like the previous owner suspected an outer CV joint (which was my first thought when you described the problem) and changing it didn't fix the issue.

I would double check that the outer CV joints look new and there is a good chance the problem could relate to one of the inner CV joints.  Diagnosing the problem will likely be a case of jacking the car up and supporting in on axle stands (if you don't have any stands to support it, DO NOT try and do this with the car only on a jack) and spinning the wheels, feeling for up-down or left-right play and spinning the wheels at full lock.  Also check for play in the drive shafts by again trying to "wiggle" them up/down and left/right.

One thing you may want to try.  Perform a tight turn with the gearbox in Neutral and see if the noise still occurs.  If it does it points to CV joints / driveshafts but if it doesn't it could be the output cups or differential on the gearbox.

Comment: Ok I'll try and have a look. I just find it odd that it could be a CV joint. Don't you think that when they would've changed them they would've changed them all? Just change the whole drive shaft with the CV joints? I'll definitely try the nutruel idea! Thank you for your response! I'm wondering if it's a loose universal ball joint, apparently Chevy's are notorious for this problem.

Comment: it is quite possible they changed one axle. If this is the case then the joints were changed, but only two of the four. It is not uncommon for the drivers  side to fail much earlier than the passenger side.  The drivers side does more of the work in propelling the car in most non all wheel drive vehicles.